# Redis laravel does not publish channel

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I am trying to publish a message in a redis channel using Laravel.
When I publish a message in the channel does not work the response return is 0 and in the redis-cli I don't see the message.

I put here the code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;

class publishController extends Controller
{

    public function test () 
    {
        $result = Redis::publish('test', json_encode(['mss' => 'here the message']));
        return $result;

    }
}
```

This is cache.php file

```
'redis' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'cache',
],
```

This is my .env file

```
REDIS_HOST=localhost
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Comment: Have you set up your redis configuration correctly in your .env and in your config/cache.php?

Comment: Does redis it work when used as a cache?

Comment: @apokryfos I update with my .env and cache.php

Comment: @EdwardChew  I update with my .env and cache.php